# Unable to increment or decrement my quantity value React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

So I am building a shopping cart, I am done with most of my code but when I try to increment or decrement the value of a product quantity from cart it just fetches me the value of current quantity it doesn't get updated.
I am unable to understand where I am making the mistake.

This is my cart.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


export default function Cart({ cart, setCart }) {
  const getTotalSum = () => {
    return cart.reduce(
      (sum, { cost, quantity }) => sum + cost * quantity,
      0
    );
  };
  const RemoveFromCart = productToRemove => {
    setCart(cart.filter(product => product !== productToRemove));
  };
  const clearCart = () => {
    setCart([])
  }

  const setQuantity = (product, amount) => {
    const newCart = [...cart];
    newCart.find(item => item.name === product.name)
      .quantity = amount;
    setCart(newCart)
  };

  let valueCal =(v)=>{
    console.log(v)
    return v++
  }
  let decrement =(v)=>{
    console.log(v)
    return v--
  }


  return (
    <>
      <h1>Cart</h1>
      {cart.length > 0 && (<button onClick={clearCart}>Clear Cart</button>)}
      <div className="products">
        {cart.map((product, idx) => (
          <div className="product" key={idx}>
            <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            <h4>RS: {product.cost}</h4>
            
            <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
            Quantity: {product.quantity}
            <button
              value={product.quantity}
              onClick={(e) =>
                setQuantity(
                  product,
                  parseInt(valueCal(e.target.value))
                )
              }
            >Add</button>
            <button
              value={product.quantity}
              onClick={(e) =>
                setQuantity(
                  product,
                  parseInt(decrement(e.target.value))
                )
              }
            >
              Drop
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => RemoveFromCart(product)}>
              Remove
        </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        Total cost: Rs: {getTotalSum()}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: `console.log(v)` what do you get here ?

Comment: Anything that needs changing in React has to be put in state.

Comment: @Shyam I always get the current value of the quantity

Comment: @GabrielLupu I will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue appears to be state mutation. When you find a matching product and set the `quantity` property you are mutating the product object and since object is still shallow reference equal React bails on rerendering it. This is why you see stale UI.

```
const setQuantity = (product, amount) => {
  const newCart = [...cart];
  newCart.find(item => item.name === product.name).quantity = amount; // mutation
  setCart(newCart)
};
```

Additionally, the `Array.prototype.find` method can potentially return `undefined` if a matching product item isn't found, and if this happens your code will throw an error when it attempts to access `quantity` of `undefined`.

You've also some odd logic around incrementing/decrementing the quantity by 1. Just add/subtract 1 from the quantity.

## Solution

Shallow copy *all* state that is being updated.

```
const setQuantity = (product, amount) => {
  setCart(cart => cart.map(item => item.name === product.name ? {
    ...item,
    quantity: item.quantity + amount
  } : item));
};
```

Fix the button callbacks. Just let the `amount` be what is added to the quantity.

```
<button onClick={(e) => setQuantity(product, 1)} >
  Add
</button>
<button onClick={(e) => setQuantity(product, -1)} >
  Drop
</button
```

Comment: Thankyou this is the best answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the value to the button and reading it and using an additional function to increment and decrement . we can just do this

```
<button onClick={(e) => setQuantity(product, product.quantity + 1)}>
    Add
</button>
<button onClick={(e) => setQuantity(product, product.quantity - 1)}>
    Drop
</button>
```

With this you can remove the additional `valueCal` and `decrement` functions .

Also instead of doing the comparison based on `item.name === product.name` , if you have an `id` key then you should consider using it which is a good practice `item.id === product.id` .

Then finally for setting the state you can use the approach suggested by @Drew Reese or @Dani.

Answer (score 2):

React will render updated state of cart when there is a state change. You will have to add a state to the cart component that increases or decreases.
for instance,

```
  this.state={item: 1}
```

Create a function that updates the state on click event,

```
this.setstate({item: this.state.item + 1})
```

Increase or decrease in quantity of products is usually a user input.First product will be added with one quantity  when user presses 'Add to Cart button'.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const setQuantity = (product, amount) => {
const newCart = [...cart].map(item => item.name === product.name ? {...item, quantity: amount} : item);
setCart(newCart)
};
```

i think the find result is not mutable